# jquery check input date is valid

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

User input date in textbox (format: YYYYMMDD), I want to check the authenticity of the user input.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-200:+0"
    });

$('#datepicker').blur(function () {
      //how to code
});
```

**function `onblur`, how to check value.
such as (datepicker range year 1816-2016)**

```
1. 20170130      =>     invalid
2. 20132901      =>     invalid
3. 20130199      =>     invalid
4. 20160130      =>     valid
5. 20120305      =>     valid
6. 79745641      =>     invalid
```

Comment: Please don't use the jQuery Validate tag when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in datepicker blur function

```
$("#datepicker").blur(function(){
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate')
        val = $(this).val();
       year =  date.getFullYear();
        val1 = Date.parse(val);
        if (year < 2016){
           alert("error")
        }
        else{
           console.log(val1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: now check it I have edited it. It was just for idea.